# How to use a function with several arguments without defining them in advance, with PHP?

Tags: php, function, twig, arguments, timber

i'm searching for a solution in PHP to use a function which can use several arguments without defining in advance the number of arguments. I know there is the function func_get_args(), but it's not quite enough... In my case i have a function that render a template with twig, and I want to give context to the template, I've made that but it's not realy proper beacause if the order of arguments change when I call the function everything is broken...

Someone have a solution?...
Thanks for your time!

```php
    public function render_with_context()
    {
        $args = func_get_args();
        
        $context['loged'] = $args[0];
        $context['agencies'] = $args[1];
        $context['login'] = $args[2];
        $context['password'] = $args[3];
        $context['active_agencies'] = $args[4];
        
        \Timber\Timber::render('views/admin.html.twig', $context);
    }
```

Comment: You could simply supply the arguments as an array to the function. And there's the [splash operator](https://lornajane.net/posts/2014/php-5-6-and-the-splat-operator) if you want it to look better.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware That's not the issue OP is experiencing. It's about the order in which the parameters are passed to the function

Comment: An associative array means you don't need to copy them, you would already have the equivalent of `$context` as a parameter.

Comment: This is not possible by default in `PHP`. You would need to test the types of the passed arguments up front before doing something with them

Comment: @DarkBee: In an array you can use keys to define which parameter it is, so that would work. The splash operator would not, I agree.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I see what you mean, that's a solution as well yeah to pass the arguments in assoc array. Was thinking to much about the signature of methods

Comment: `render_with_context` is frankly pretty superfluous. It doesn't really do anything useful, and what it does do, it does badly (trying to map positional args to names, which is somewhat impossible if they're all optional). Just do `Timber::render('...', ['loged' => ..., ...])` directly from the caller.

Comment: Thanks you! I've made a associative array when i call the function, it worked !

Answer (score 0):

I've made that, it worked realy well!

```php
$this->render_with_context([
    'loged' => $loged, 
    'agencies' => $agencies, 
    'login' => $bdd_login, 
    'password' => $bdd_password,
    'active_agencies' => $active_agencies
]);
```

```php
public function render_with_context() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $context['loged'] = $args[0]['loged'];
    $context['agencies'] = $args[0]['agencies'];
    $context['login'] = $args[0]['login'];
    $context['password'] = $args[0]['password'];
    $context['active_agencies'] = $args[0]['active_agencies'];
    \Timber\Timber::render('views/admin.html.twig', $context);
}
```

Comment: Reassigning from one array to another with the same names is very, *very* superfluous. You can condense that down to `$context = $args[0]`. And then condense that down to `function render_with_context($context)`. And then delete `render_with_context` altogether and just call `Timber::render('...', ['loged' => ...])` directly.

Comment: @Sivvv You shouldn't use the code snippet tool for code that doesn't actually run

Comment: @DarkBee Why not? What should I use in this case? (sorry I'm a junior..)